# How do i change the expiry time for password reset link ad b2c user flow?

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, reset-password

I have this azure ad b2c user flow for password reset which we send to the user for setup a new password. Is there a way that I can change the expiration for this link? As an example when visited the link after 20 minutes page tells the user that the link has been expired.

I tried going through the azure docs but there was no mentioning on this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea to do this by making a gateway URL through my web application so that I can check the POSIX time compared to the db saved time and do this validation and continue from there.